# Get translate3d values of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say a div has this applied to it:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -200px, 0px)
```

How could I retrieve those values with jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried using [`jQuery.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The value gets stored either as a `matrix` or a `matrix3d`, depending on whether or not the z value was set.  Assuming no other transformations, for a 2D matrix, X and Y are the last two values.  For a 3D matrix, X, Y, Z, 1 are the last four digits.

You could use a regular expression to get the values:

```
function getTransform(el) {
    var results = $(el).css('-webkit-transform').match(/matrix(?:(3d)\(\d+(?:, \d+)*(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+)), \d+\)|\(\d+(?:, \d+)*(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+))\))/)

    if(!results) return [0, 0, 0];
    if(results[1] == '3d') return results.slice(2,5);

    results.push(0);
    return results.slice(5, 8);
}
```

Comment: You can just get `css('transform')` now as jQuery normalizes vendor prefixes.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer by Trevor, this does NOT WORK for negative values!!

Comment: This logic + @trevor-lundeen 's response work like a charm

Comment: Can anyone help me out with this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62437585/13399106

Answer (score 14):

If you change the accepted answer's match() pattern to this it adds support for negative numbers:

```
$(el).css('-webkit-transform').match(/matrix(?:(3d)\(-{0,1}\d+(?:, -{0,1}\d+)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+)), -{0,1}\d+\)|\(-{0,1}\d+(?:, -{0,1}\d+)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))\))/)
```

Comment: this is returning null in my case

Answer (score 8):

I don't know about the various edge cases, but in my case it's always 3 values like 'translate3d(23px, 34px, 40px)', so this was the cleanest way I could find:

```
function getMatrix(element) {
    const values = element.style.transform.split(/\w+\(|\);?/);
    const transform = values[1].split(/,\s?/g).map(parseInt);

    return {
      x: transform[0],
      y: transform[1],
      z: transform[2]
    };
}
```

Result:

```
{x: 238, y: 0, z: 0}
```

Comment: For 'transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)' I am getting { x: 0, y: NaN, z: 0 } :))

Answer (score 4):

Here is a regular expression I use that returns named groups for x, y, and z. I find it a bit easier on the eyes and to work with:

```
const re = /translate3d\((?<x>.*?)px, (?<y>.*?)px, (?<z>.*?)px/
```

You can use it like this:

```
const transform = element.style.transform;
const re = /translate3d\((?<x>.*?)px, (?<y>.*?)px, (?<z>.*?)px/
const results = re.exec(transform);
console.log(results.groups.x, results.groups.y, results.groups.z);
```

Comment: This is a real treat! Very nice John!

Answer (score 2):

If you update the regular expression to the following it adds supports for those odd cases when your transform has floats:

```
/matrix(?:(3d)\(-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*(?:, -{0,1}\d+\.?\d*)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*)), -{0,1}\d+\.?\d*\)|\(-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*(?:, -{0,1}\d+\.?\d*)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))\))/
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't add comment to @parliament answer so I'll write here.

Be careful with `map(parseInt)` because `['1', '7', '11'].map(parseInt) returns [1, NaN, 3]` [source](https://medium.com/dailyjs/parseint-mystery-7c4368ef7b21).

Better to use `.map(numStr => parseInt(numStr))`

```js
function getMatrix(element) {
    const values = element.style.transform.split(/\w+\(|\);?/);
    const transform = values[1].split(/,\s?/g).map(numStr => parseInt(numStr));

    return {
      x: transform[0],
      y: transform[1],
      z: transform[2]
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This is wrong, ignore this.**

I think if you do something like...

```
var styles = $('.myclass').css('-webkit-transform');
```

You would probably get the `translate3d(0px, -200px, 0px)` back.

Maybe you could then parse that string? seems like a bit of a hack though.

Comment: no, you would get a matrix back like this: `matrix(-1, -0.00000000000000012246467991473532, 0.00000000000000012246467991473532, -1, 0, 0) `

Comment: ah right! uch! That's why I said *think*, *probably* and *maybe* :)