# How do I get the absolute value of translate3d?

Tags: javascript, css, translate3d

How would I go about converting a negative translate3d value into a positive number?

For example:

```
var val = $m('slider').style.webkitTransform;
console.log(val); // this returns a number like: translate3d(-93px, 0, 0);
```

How would I go about converting the values into positive numbers so that my output is:

```
translate3d(93px, 0, 0); // positive 93
```

Comment: By "convert" are you asking for absolute value or what?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: val = `translat3(-93px, 0 , 0)` or just `93px, 0, 0)` ?

Comment: `Math.abs();` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp

Comment: Math.abs(val); doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to keep track of your coords also in JS if you can, but if this isnt possible, you need to [parse out the individual values from the transform matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982053/get-translate3d-values-of-a-div)...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3gBYB/)

If you get the computed style of the transform (not just the `.style` property) using `getComputedStyle` it will return a matrix:

```
// adapted from jQuery solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982053/get-translate3d-values-of-a-div
function getTransform(el) {
    var transform = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform');
    var results = transform.match(/matrix(?:(3d)\(-{0,1}\d+(?:, -{0,1}\d+)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+)), -{0,1}\d+\)|\(-{0,1}\d+(?:, -{0,1}\d+)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))\))/);

    if(!results) return [0, 0, 0];
    if(results[1] == '3d') return results.slice(2,5);

    results.push(0);
    return results.slice(5, 8); // returns the [X,Y,Z,1] values
}


var translation = getTransform( $m('slider') );
var translationX = translation[0];
var absX = Math.abs(translationX);
```

Comment: Hi, how would I go about dynamically setting these three new positive coordinates to new container such as: $clockcontainer.style.webkitTransform = (absX);

Comment: I essentially need set positive coordinates to another div because I am moving in the opposite position of another 3dtransform

Comment: I don't need one particular coordinate value, I would need all three values but set to a new div so that it can dynamically change.

Comment: As you can see in the answer above, the getTransform function returns the x,y, and z coords in an array. Run those values through Math.abs and you you can form a new translate with that. take a look at this new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3gBYB/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how you could separate all of the values using `split`, parsing the integer values using `parseInt` and then getting the absolute value using `abs()`

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bXgCP/

```
var mystr = "93px, 0, 10";

var myarr = mystr.split(",");
var finalStr = '';

for (var i=0;i<myarr.length;i++)
{ 

    myarr[i] = Math.abs(parseInt(myarr[i]),10);
}

finalStr = myarr.join(); // put the values back with the `,` format
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Adam has a bug:  It cannot handle decimal values like this:

```
matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 100.000002649095, 100.000002649095)
```

Adapted regex to allow it:

```
function getTransform(el) {
    var transform = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform');
    var results = transform.match(/matrix(?:(3d)\(-{0,1}\d+(?:, -{0,1}\d+)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+)), -{0,1}\d+\)|\(-{0,1}\d+(?:, -{0,1}\d+)*(?:, (-{0,1}.+))(?:, (-{0,1}.+))\))/);

    if(!results) return [0, 0, 0];
    if(results[1] == '3d') return results.slice(2,5);

    results.push(0);
    return results.slice(5, 8); // returns the [X,Y,Z,1] values
}
```

Comment: you have typo space in "-webkit- transform"