# If element translate 3d ... addClass

Tags: jquery, setinterval, detect, translate3d

how can I write a script that does this?

If the div class "test" has the property `translate3d (0px, 100px, 0px)` add to this the "active" class else remove it.

I tried something like this but it's not right ...

```
setInterval(function(){
  if($('.test').css('transform') == 'translate3d(0px, 100px, 0px)') {
    $('.test').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.test').removeClass('active');
  }
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like below  using regex match:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.test').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).css('transform') == 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 100)');
    if($(this).css('transform') == "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 100)"){
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" style="transform:translate3d(0px, 100px, 0px)">Hello</div><br/><br/>
<div class="test" style="transform:translate3d(10px, 10px, 100px)">Hello</div>
```

Note:- check the `console.log()` value and you will see it's a matrix

Reference Taken:- [Get translate3d values of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7982594/4248328)

To check any element have transform property or not use below regex:-

`/matrix(?:(3d)\(\d+(?:, \d+)*(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+)), \d+\)|\(\d+(?:, \d+)*(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+))\))/)`

Comment: Thanks, now I document on the regex match.
I do not understand in your example qul the control value: if I wanted to color "hello" red only when it comes to translate3d (0px, 100px, 0px) and not when there is another value.

Comment: @Andrea  i have changed my code now. Please check and let me know you get it or not?

Comment: Thank you now I understand where I was wrong.
Thank you!!

Comment: @Andrea  glad to help you :):)

Comment: Can any one help me out with this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62437585/13399106