# Is it possible to get the transform:translate3d() values of an element ? By using Angular Typescript?

Tags: java, html, css, angular, typescript

So i need the following values: [Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8r8d.png)

I want to get them and save them in a variable for example. Do you have any suggestions for me ?
I want to get them to save the last position of an element. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to your element you can use a reference to it with a ViewChild for example https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild and then you can use

```
myElementRef.style.transform
```

This will only give you a string containing the value of the property *transform*. If you want to access the values you would have to parse the string.

Comment: A function to do the parsing can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982053/get-translate3d-values-of-a-div.

Comment: So how can i use the function u post ?